# Easier way to get daily pictures with pandas.Timestamp on x-axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is there a way to plot a graph with daily data from the past, where on the x-axis the timestamps go from 16 o'clock till 06 o'clock the next morning.
I managed to get it with:

```
Begin = "".join((Year, Month, Day, ' 16:00'))
End = "".join((Yearend, Monthend, Dayend, ' 06:00'))
ax3.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp(Begin), pd.Timestamp(End))
```

I was wondering if there is another way without "the" extra code, I tried this without succes:

```
ax.set_xlim(pandas.Timestamp('16:00'), pandas.Timestamp('06:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using matplotlib, so I'm not sure about the plotting, but if you wanted a certain time frame for each day in the past, you can use [`df.between_time()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html)

Comment: Because of your link I found something what decreases the amount of code needed. There is a function Timedelta which adds an amount of hours to the 16 o'clock time. So thanks for the try, it helpt  me in the end.